# Link to download adb for Mac,please?

Tags: cyanogenmod, adb

sorry but i cannot find a link to download adb for Mac..can somebody provide me a link,please?thank you!

Comment: http://android.izzysoft.de/downloads has downloads for Linux, Mac, and Windows – for a [minimal installation of ADB](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/42474/16575) (see the linked question and its answers for details).

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://code.google.com/p/adb-fastboot-install/) is the home project page for adb and fast boot install for Mac from Google.

[Here](http://code.google.com/p/adb-fastboot-install/downloads/list) is the download page from the same source.

## description

this script installs ADB and Fastboot to /usr/local/bin/ on Mac OS X. You can uninstall using the Uninstall ADB.sh script provided.

## how to install

- from terminal

Run ADB Install Mac.sh from Terminal (/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app) and then restart Terminal. If you wish to uninstall, simply run Uninstall ADB.sh ADB and Fastboot will be moved to /usr/local/bin/

- from command

On Mac OS X (and some Linux distros) you can drag and drop your install file into your terminal windows and press return (or enter) and the script will run.